# Chrome extension - How to know if own extension blocked page - manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-declarativenetrequest

When blocking pages with a pattern like so:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  addRules: [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "priority": 1,
      "action": {"type": "block"},
      "condition": {
        "urlFilter": "*://*/*lala.js",
        "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

i get a page error:

> ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

What would be the best way to tell the user that my extension blocked this page?

Comment: You can redirect to an html file in your extension that says it. See `extensionPath` in documentation. It must be also listed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Comment: ah ok, that means if one wants to make visible that it is its own extension is blocking, one blocks by redirecting? like so: `"action": { "type": "redirect", "redirect": { "extensionPath": "/a.jpg" } }`

Comment: would there be any way to state in the Pop-Up that it was your extension blocking/redirecting?

Comment: No, use an html file. Inside it put the text/images you want to show.

Comment: if i block assets by using `"resourceTypes" : ["script"]`, there is also no way to notify the user that the asset was blocked?

Comment: You can increase the number on the badge, see chrome.declarativeNetRequest.setExtensionActionOptions.